# Interceptor not setting the authorization token

Tags: token, httpclient, interceptor, angular6

Hi I'm trying to write a simple Angular 6 interceptor that adds the jwt token to the header when sending requests.

The problem is that the header in the request arrives NULL on the backend, so of course I can't get the authorization token and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

I'm pretty sure the problem is in my js code because if I try to send the same request via any REST client I can see the header in my Java code just fine.

Here's my js code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
/*         this.users_from_db=data; */
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

  users_from_db: Observable<any>;
}



import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return  this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/users/get-all');
  }

}



import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpSentEvent, HttpHeaderResponse, HttpProgressEvent,
  HttpResponse, HttpUserEvent, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {TokenStorage} from './token.storage';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

const TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = 'Authorization';

@Injectable()
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private token: TokenStorage, private router: Router) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
    let authReq = req;
    if (this.token.getToken() != null) {
      console.log("authorizing...");
      authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + this.token.getToken())});
      console.log(authReq);
    }
    if (!authReq.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
      authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
    }

    return next.handle(authReq).do(
        (err: any) => {
          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log('req url :: ' + req.url);
            if (err.status === 401) {
              this.router.navigate(['login']);
            }
          }
        }
      );
  }

}
```

The value of the token is surely there when I do `this.token.getToken()`in the intercept function. I checked by printing the value in the browser console.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: look at there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990474/angular-6-http-interceptors-request-headers-not-modified/50994021#50994021

Answer (score 1):

This is my interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse, HttpInterceptor } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, map, filter, take, switchMap, finalize } from "rxjs/operators";
import { AppConsts } from "../consts";

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {        
        return next.handle(this.addTokenToRequest(request)).pipe(
            map(res => res),
            catchError(err => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401 && err.headers.has("Token-Expired")) {
                    // here code to refresh token if needed
                } else {
                    return throwError(err);
                }
            })
        );
    }

    private addTokenToRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string = null): HttpRequest<any> {
        if (token) {
            request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });
        }
        else {
            const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(AppConsts.DEFAULT_USER_STORAGE_NAME));
            if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
                request = request.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

You also can see a simple example - http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial