# Angular 6 - Add JWT bearer token to header not working

Tags: jwt, angular6, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to add the auth bearer token header while getting a comment from the asp.net core 2.2 backend in angular 6

```
getComment(postId: number): Observable<IComment[]>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken);
    console.log(authToken);
    return this.httpClient.get<IComment[]>('api/comment/post/' + postId, { headers });
  }
```

This piece of code is not working. I am getting a value from console.log(authToken). When I copy the token in Postman, everything is working fine.

My login function in a service. This is working fine to, i'm getting the token from the backend.

```
 login(login: ILogin) {
    console.log(login);
    return this.http
      .post('api/auth/login', login)
      .pipe(map((res: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this._authNavStatusSource.next(true);
        return true;
      }));
  }
```

When I remove authorization from the action in the backend, getting the comments is working fine. As you can see in the image below, the jwt token is just not being add to the header.

Postman:
[image: Postman]

Header information from chrome
[image: Header Information]

Comment: The issue might be related to CORS. Postman is a different client than the browser, of course. Can you tell what is the response you get in your browser; like using Developer Tools and Network tab?

Comment: it is better to use Interceptor for these purposes. See example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396931/interceptor-not-setting-the-authorization-token/51416245#51416245

Comment: For now I just want to it the easy way and add the token to the header. I have a lot to do for school to, time is limited.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the headers in `{ headers }` section.
Change `return this.httpClient.get<IComment[]>('api/comment/post/' + postId, { headers });` to `return this.httpClient.get<IComment[]>('api/comment/post/' + postId, { headers: headers });`

Comment: Hello, I already tried that. { headers: headers} but that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it's working fine via Postman, and that this is not a CORS issue (i.e., either CORS is enabled, or your JS is being served from the same origin as you API), I assume you're already subscribing to the returned `Observable<IComment[]>`.

The code above won't issue the request until there is a call somewhere that looks like this:

```
yourService.getComment(postId).subscribe(comments => { ... });
```

That will begin consuming the `Observable` and trigger the underlying HTTP request.

Comment: Hello, yes I use subscribe. When I put [AllowAnonymous] and the action I receive the comment list as intended. 
this._commentService.getComment(this.activeRoute.snapshot.params.id).subscribe(data => this.comments = data);