# Http Header In Angular 6

Tags: header, angular6

This is my service i am using...
Request header not showing any access authorization.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

import { Config } from "../config";


@Injectable()
export class HomeService {

   headers: any;
   options: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
        this.headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
        this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('userToken'));
        this.options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});
   }

    getLoginUserDetails(){
         return this.http.post(Config.apiEndPoint + "get-login-user", { headers: this.options});
    }
```

}

Is there any solution let me know.

Comment: Can you share an example of what you expect vs. what you actually get

Comment: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: using laravel 5.6 with angular 6

Comment: you need to configure your backend services to accept request from localhost:4200, then you need to set authorized headers in your backend service. look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990474/angular-6-http-interceptors-request-headers-not-modified/50994021#50994021